# alternative promise() function for css transitions

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I made a game with 8*8 div elements that are animating, currently i'm using the animation function in JQuery.

When i call the function the animations start, i use the following code to check if the animations all stopped:

```
function start_animation()
{
  //the animations start here
  $("div").promise().done(function() {
     //here comes the code for when the animations stoped
  }
}
```

Now i want to do the animations with css transitions, but i can't find a solution to check if all animations are done.

I tried:

```
$("div").bind("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", function(){ ... });
```

But this gives a callback everytime 1 animation is done.

Is there another way to accomplish this?

Comment: For a very quick hacky fix you could use a counter, which only executes when counter == 64 ?

Comment: Adding a jsfiddle will make it easy for others to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Check out what the `promise` function does https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/queue.js#L119. You will need to use a similar code, only that you will not hook `resolve` on the animation queue but bind it as the event handler.

In short:

```
function start_animation() {
  var divs = $("div");
  // the animations start here

  var count = divs.length;
  // using `.one` automatically unbinds the handler
  divs.one("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", function() {
    if ( --count == 0) {
      // here comes the code for when all the animations stoped
    }
  }
}
```